# heroku migrations silently failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, heroku-postgres

Note: this is my first time configuring a rails application, deploying a rails app and setting up a database. I very well might be doing something obviously stupid.

I have a working rails application setup with postgres 9.3. I can run migrations, run my server locally and get a running application locally.

I pushed my code up to heroku and at one point it ran. Now when I run the heroku console it shows that my database is totally empty and I cannot figure out how to recreate it.

I am using v 0.17.1 of the pg gem.

Here are the steps I have taken.

1) Created my database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: fr_development
  pool: 5
  username: user
  password: password

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: fr_test
  pool: 5
  username: user
  password: password

production:
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
```

1.5) setup my heroku account and installed papertrail

2) Made sure my schema.rb and all migrations are under source control.

3) ran "git push heroku master"

4) ran "heroku run db:drop db:setup --app app" or alternately sometime "heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL"

5)  ran "heroku run rake db:migrate --app app"

6) ran "heroku restart --app app"

Basically no matter what I run, all i get in papertrail is:

```
Nov 09 11:19:50 app heroku/api:  Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:drop db:create db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production` by email@gmail.com 
Nov 09 11:19:53 app heroku/run.3003:  Awaiting client 
Nov 09 11:19:53 app heroku/run.3003:  Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:drop db:create db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production` 
Nov 09 11:19:53 app heroku/run.3003:  State changed from starting to up 
Nov 09 11:19:54 app heroku/run.3003:  Process exited with status 0 
Nov 09 11:19:54 app heroku/run.3003:  State changed from up to complete
```

And then if I hit my server Ill get an error that one of my relations doesnt exist.

If I "heroku run console" and try to run any of my tables it will say they dont exist.

One thing I no nothing about and am having a hard time finding resources to learn about is proper configurations for bin directory stuff. I have not touched

my bin/bundle is totally empty

```
#!bin/rails

begin
  load File.expand_path("../spring", __FILE__)
rescue LoadError
end
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application',  __FILE__)
require_relative '../config/boot'
require 'rails/commands'
```

.

```
#bin/rake
begin
  load File.expand_path("../spring", __FILE__)
rescue LoadError
end
require_relative '../config/boot'
require 'rake'
Rake.application.run
```

.

```
#bin/spring
unless defined?(Spring)
  require "rubygems"
  require "bundler"

  if match = Bundler.default_lockfile.read.match(/^GEM$.*?^    spring \((.*?)\)$.*?^$/m)
    ENV["GEM_PATH"] = ([Bundler.bundle_path.to_s] + Gem.path).join(File::PATH_SEPARATOR)
    ENV["GEM_HOME"] = ""
    Gem.paths = ENV

    gem "spring", match[1]
    require "spring/binstub"
  end
end
```

if I run heroku pg:info i get

```
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_ONYX_URL (DATABASE_URL)
Plan:        Hobby-dev
Status:      Available
Connections: 1/20
PG Version:  9.3.3
Created:     2014-11-06 04:08 UTC
Data Size:   6.5 MB
Tables:      0
Rows:        0/10000 (In compliance)
Fork/Follow: Unsupported
Rollback:    Unsupported
```

One last thing that may be relevant I keep seeing this stack trace in paper trail although I'm not sure if it is just what happens when I reset the app:

```
[2014-11-10 03:39:58] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM 
Nov 09 19:39:58 app app/web.1:      /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select' 
Nov 09 19:39:58 app app/web.1:      /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start' 
Nov 09 19:39:58 app app/web.1:      /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start' 
Nov 09 19:39:58 app app/web.1:      /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start' 
Nov 09 19:39:58 app app/web.1:      /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:14:in `run' 
Nov 09 19:39:58 app app/web.1:      /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start' 
Nov 09 19:39:58 app app/web.1:      /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in `start'
```

I have really tried to debug this one but I am out of ideas. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

other note: I setup postgres for the first time right before this. I was mucking around with it alot destorying and creating users and destroying and creating tables but I got everything back to a functional state locally. Don't know if that could somehow play into this.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make sure, if you haven't already, first run:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

And if then if that doesn't work:

```
heroku pg:reset
```

Followed by the heroku run rake db:migrate again.

By the way, I don't think Heroku gives you permission to to drop or create. Thus they've implemented pg:reset.

I found the devcenter doc that mentions permissions for dropping and creating and on using pg:reset here:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rake

Comment: While the migrate thing was a good catch, it was just an error in my documenting the process. I have probably run the migrations on heroku literally 20 times.

I went back through and tried again with several orderings of heroku pg:reset and then running the migration or vice versa but still no dice.