# Rake db:migrate fails silently on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rake

I have an app which I can run locally with env=prod and which can be deployed but I cannot run any rake commands on heroku.

- I got my server running locally in ENV=production. It failed the exact same way as on heroku before I created my database and then worked fine after I did a db:setup. The problem is definately that my commands to create the db on heroku are failing.
- If I run "heroku run echo "hello" i get output "hello". My general ability to run commands on Heroku is not the issue.
- but if I run "heroku run rake [ANY_COMMAND] I get no output and a silent failure.
- if i do heroku run bash and then rake db:migrate without specifying an evironment it runs fine
- if I do heroku run bash and then rake db:migrate ENV="production" i get

  ```
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
  ```

and then nothing else. just back to an active bash prompt. no error

- if i do heroku run bash and then rake db:setup RAILS_ENV="production" i get:

  ```
  FATAL:  permission denied for database "postgres"
  DETAIL:  User does not have CONNECT privilege.
  ```

  Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "username"=>"dangfjubjcfyxp", "password"=>random string of characters[REDACTED], "port"=>5432, "database"=>[REDACTED]}

Not sure if that is just because you should not run that command on heroku or if that is actually an issue.

- if I go into heroku pg:psql and run \l (list tables) or \dg (list users) I got huge tables full of gibberish. Not sure if that is to be expected or not.
- blew my heroku app away and started from scratch and got the same results

  ```
  #ROOT/bin/rake
  #!/usr/bin/env ruby
  begin
    load File.expand_path("../spring", __FILE__)
  rescue LoadError
  end
  require_relative '../config/boot'
  require 'rake'
  Rake.application.run
  ```

This makes me feel that maybe one of my bin directory configs regarding rake is screwed up. Maybe a reference to "PATH" ?

Some other possible relevant files:

```
#ROOT/Procfile
web: bundle exec rails server thin -p $PORT -e $RACK_ENV

#ROOT/config/production.rb
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like nginx, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this).
  config.serve_static_assets = true

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Set to :debug to see everything in the log.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Disable automatic flushing of the log to improve performance.
  # config.autoflush_log = false

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

Please let me know if it would be helpful for me to post any other files

I had another similiar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26832755/heroku-migrations-silently-failing) which shows some more of my files but I think my understanding has sufficiently changed to totally reframe the question so I though a new post would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if is behavior desribed is actually and issue, but the workflow seems flawed.

You should develop you app locally, run migrations etc, then commit your changes and `git push heroku master` - heroku after receiving push will do all the work: create new blob, run migrations for you, and then restart the app (run all web processes and worker processes as defined in Procfile: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile).

If it's just standard plain rails app you don't even need procfile - just push it to heroku.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I need to run heroku run rake db:seed, and then it all worked.